# capture records 6 months prior to current month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm working off a query where the dates are declared as integers, it's meant for a revenue report that captures the last 6 months back from x month/year.  So user inputs say 10 (oct), 2014. What I want is for it to go 6 months back (10-6) and show all of the records in this range.  I would think it would be something like csr.csrdatepulled >= dateadd(mm,-6.@month)   -- however I don't think this works since they're integers. Right now it will just capture that month, but not the in-between. Is there a way to accomplish this with month and year declared as ints?  Thanks in advance, this is a slimmed down query-

```
declare
 @Month int,
 @Year int

Set @Month = 10
Set @Year = 2014

select csr.csrdatepulled


from   CustomServicesForRevenue csr
where DatePart(MM,csr.CsrDatePulled) = @Month and DatePart(yyyy,csr.CsrDatePulled) = @Year

order by csr.CsrDAtepulled desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a complete date (the 1st of the month & year) deducting 6 months and fetch rows that are >= to it

```
WHERE 
csr.CsrDatePulled >= DATEADD(MONTH, @MONTH - 1 - 6, DATEADD(YEAR, @YEAR - 1900, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it makes sense that you would create the date then work from there, good to know!